# How to assign values in a struct using for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

---

```
function [den, p] = findUpperBound(data)
newData = data;
ranData = data;
pValue = Inf;
density = 0.99;
decr = 0.01;
x = [];
y = [];
while(pValue>0.05)
   for i=1:numel(data)
       newData(i).matrix = findNetworkAtDensity(density, 0.01, data(i).matrix);
       newData(i).smallWorldness = (sum(clustering_coef_wu(newData(i).matrix))/90)/avgPathLen(newData(i).matrix);
       x(i,1) = newData(i).matrix; 
       ranData(i).matrix = randmio_und_connected(newData(i).matrix, 5);
       ranData(i).smallWorldness = (sum(clustering_coef_wu(ranData(i).matrix))/90)/avgPathLen(ranData(i).matrix);
       y(i,1) = ranData(i).matrix;
   end
   [h, pValue] = ttest2(x,y);
   density = density - decr;
end
den = density;
p = pValue;
```

end

---

I need to assign some values into newData and ranData, and there is an error:

```
"Improper index matrix reference. Error in findUpperBound (line 11)newData(i).matrix = findNetworkAtDensity(density, 0.01, data(i).matrix);"
```

It is weird that if I use the command window to do this, there will be no error:

```
>> a = data;
>> a(1).matrix = data(1).matrix;
>>
```

I've search for this on the Matlab site, but still can't find the answer. 
Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `findNetworkAtDensity` return?

Comment: It returns a 90-by-90 matrix, and **a** is a struct which contains 36 matrix.

Comment: Have you checked that it is returning what you are expecting given those inputs?

Comment: Yes I've check that. It is just what I expect.
The error happens when using for loop to run this.
It seems that I cannot using an index **i** to get a value in a struct....

Comment: How does `data` look like? Is it an array of structs?

Comment: **data** is a 1*36 struct which contains 36 90-by-90 matrix with field name **matrix**.